# Change key for f90-start-abbrev

Tags: key-bindings, abbrev

Emacs defines ` to be used for abbrevs in f90 mode. How do I change this so some other key, like e.g. # ? I think, I found the relevant lines in f90.el:

```
(defvar f90-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map "`"        'f90-abbrev-start)
    ...
```

but my attempts at mimicking this syntax usually lead to errors.

Thanks in advance for any help.

## Update:

So I followed the advice of Aaron Harris and added:

```
(eval-after-load 'f90
  '(define-key f90-mode-map (kbd "#") #'f90-abbrev-start))
```

to my .emacs. Now when I open a Fortran file and hit

```
C-h k #
```

I get the following text:

> `#` runs the command f90-abbrev-start, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
>     function in `f90.el'.
>
> It is bound to #, `.
>
> (f90-abbrev-start)
>
> Typing `C-h or`? lists all the F90 abbrevs.
>    Any other key combination is executed normally.

But still

```
`su<SPACE>
```

is expanded to subroutine while

```
#su<SPACE>
```

is not. Do I misunderstand something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, after actually looking at the `f90-mode` code, it looks like `f90-abbrev-start` doesn't really do much except call `self-insert-command` and relies on every entry in `f90-mode-abbrev-table` to start with a backquote.

One solution would be to modify `f90-mode-abbrev-table` so the abbreviations all start with a hash character instead of a backquote, but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that isn't messy.

The other possibility that occurs to me would be to remap the key on the input event level rather than the command level, so that the call to `self-insert-command` sees a backquote.  I think this should work:

```
(define-key f90-mode-map (kbd "#") (kbd "`")
```

---

Original, not-particularly-helpful answer:

From the snippet you posted, you probably want to write:

```el
(define-key f90-mode-map (kbd "#") #'f90-abbrev-start)
```

Note that the only significant departure from the code in the snippet is the lack of `defvar` and `let` forms.  This is because those are being used to *define* the variable `f90-mode-map`, and you just want to modify the variable as it already exists.

The other two minor changes here are less important:

1. Exchanging `"#"` for `(kbd "#")` does nothing here (since `(kbd "#")` returns `"#"`), but it's good practice to get into when defining key bindings, because `kbd` will return the correct answer in pretty much all circumstances, whereas a bare string won't always work.
2. The use of the sharp quote (`#'f90-abbrev-start` vs. `'f90-abbrev-start`) just tells Emacs that we are talking about the function `f90-abbrev-start` rather than the variable `f90-abbrev-start` (which may or may not be defined).  I don't believe this matters unless you're byte-compiling the file in question, but putting it in is considered good practice.  Also, it makes function references easier to distinguish visually, which I find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made some advances, something still doesn't work.

Comment: @Laurent: Answer updated.  Hopefully this new approach will work for you.  Sorry for not doing more research before jumping in with my original answer.

Comment: Works like a charm now!